# find all continuous path segments in an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have an undirected graph, like the following:

```
.      C
.    /   \   
.   B      F
.  /      / \
. A      D   E
```

The edges are:

```
A-B
B-C
C-F
D-F
E-F
```

I want to identify every continuous path segment in this graph, which is: (nodes of each path given in alphabetical order)

A, B, C, D, E, F, AB, BC, CF, DF, EF, ABC, BCF, CDF, CEF, DEF, ABCF, BCDF, BCEF, CDEF, ABCDF, ABCEF, BCDEF, and ABCDEF

Is there a name for this task? Any relevant algorithms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm overinterpreting the example and its presentation in the Question, but if the problem is determining all simple (no retracing edges) paths in an undirected cycle-free connected graph, i.e. a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)), there is a simple Answer.

Given there are $n$ nodes in the tree, any pair of (not necessarily distinct) nodes uniquely determines a simple path (trivial in the case of identical nodes).  Thus there are $n$ trivial paths (no edges) and $\binom{n}{2}$ nontrivial paths (at least one edge), for a total of $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ paths.  This agrees with the example, having $n=6$ nodes and $24$ paths.

If the task were to generate all pairs paths, then [Johnson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm), with all edges having weight 1, would be attractive.  More discussion of that task in [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58198/3111).

Comment: Thanks for the response. You guessed right; all of my graphs are trees, but the paths aren't necessarily simple, like CDEF. Strange that your calculation came up with the right number of paths with a faulty assumption.

Comment: You chose to alphabetize the nodes, so it's unclear what "path" CDEF is supposed to represent, even allowing retracing of edges.  However if retracing of edges were allowed, there would be infinitely many paths just for a single edge.  Maybe instead of [paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)), you have in mind connected subgraphs?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think connected subgraphs are what I had in mind, not paths. I found this article, which will hopefully give me some good ideas. http://www.math.unl.edu/~shartke2/math/papers/k-subgraphs.pdf